# Is this matrix decomposition possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Given a $2\times2$ matrix $S$ with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ , when is it possible to write $S=\frac{1}{3}(ABC+CAB+BCA)$ such that $A+B+C=0$, where $A, B, C$ are matrices over the same ground ring as S. Always? How would I find $A, B, C$?

Comment: Just a comment, which I'm not sure helps in answering your question, is that $3S=ABC+CAB+BCA$ with $A+B+C=0$ is the same as requiring $3S=A^3+B^3-(A+B)^3$.

Comment: @user1551 I can't derive your result. Would you mind to show me/give me some pointers. Anyway, splitting off the tracefree part might be worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Since the trace of $A,B,C$ is invariant under any permutation, maybe it is possible to take the matrices symmetric. (The trace of all products of three symmetric matrices is the same)

Comment: @vuur When $A,B,C$ are polynomials in $X$, they commute. Hence $S=-AB(A+B)$. As $X$ is 2x2 and traceless, by Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $X^2=-dI$. In turn, $X^3=-dX$. Therefore you can express $=-AB(A+B)$ as a linear combination of $X$ and $I$. By comparing coefficients with $S=aX+bI$, you get the two equations that I mentioned in the previous comment. Since this is an underdetermined system, I think there is a chance that it is always solvable, but I don't know if this is really the case.

Comment: For the case of matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$: clearly all diagonal $S$ can be represented if the diagonal elements are of the form $-xy(x+y)$ with integers $x,y$. Just take diagonal $A$ and $B$ with such $x$ and $y$. Already for $S=I_2$ this does not work, since $-xy(x+y)=1$ has no integer solution. On the other hand, with
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & \\ -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, \; B=I_2,\; C=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 & \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
we have $A+B+C=0$ and $S=(ABC+CAB+BCA)/3=I_2$.

Answer (score 1):

To challenge this knot, we have no choice but to replace any specific matrices.
As one of the approaches, The rotation matrix is a part of correct answer. Because the matrix has special characteristics. As reasons, variables and equations can be reduced and commutativity is allowed under any two dimension. For example, the following figure shows that even if rotating operations are exchanged, eventual angles are corresponded as  same direction. Therefore, this property can be applied to supply the better solution.

[image]

Initially, let replace $\{A,B,C\}$ with rotation matrices $\{R_{a},R_{b},R_{c}\}$. Further, rotation matrix can be handled to be identity with Euler formula:

$$
R_{a}=R(a)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{(a)} & -\sin{(a)} \\
\sin{(a)} & \cos{(a)}
\end{bmatrix}  
\equiv e^{ia}
$$

Then the supplied top equation can be expressed by follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
3S
=& ABC+BCA+CAB \\
=& R_{a}R_{b}R_{c}+R_{b}R_{c}R_{a}+R_{c}R_{a}R_{b} \\
S=& R_{a}R_{b}R_{c} \\
\Leftrightarrow
e^{i\phi}=& e^{ia} e^{ib} e^{ic} =e^{i(a+b+c)}  \\
\end{aligned} \\
$$

where, $S\equiv e^{i\phi}$ and $\phi$ is phase degree. Next, the bottom constraint equation is:

$$
O=R_{a}+R_{b}+R_{c} \\
\Leftrightarrow
0=e^{ia} + e^{ib} + e^{ic}
$$

Hence, two equations can be expressed by the following simultaneous equation:

$$
\begin{cases}
a+b+c=\phi \\
e^{ia}+e^{ib}+e^{ic}=0
\end{cases}
$$

We can solve to replace as $\delta_{1}=c-a$ and $\delta_{2}=c-b$. Eventually, the solutions are below (However, these parameters are limited on range of $[0 \ \ 2\pi + \phi]$):

$$
(a,b,c)
=\biggl\{
\cfrac{\phi}{3},
\cfrac{\phi+2\pi}{3},
\cfrac{\phi+4\pi}{3}
\biggr\}
$$

Therefore, the top equation can be calculated as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
S
=& R_{a}R_{b}R_{c} \\
=& R_{\phi /3}(R_{\phi /3} R_{120^\circ})(R_{\phi /3} R_{240^\circ}) \\
=& R_{\phi /3}^3R_{(120+240)^\circ} \\
R_{\phi}=& R_{\phi/3}^3
\end{aligned}
$$

This means that end phase is exactly three times of initial phase. This notion can be drawn on unit ring like following figure. Of course, these operations can be exchangeable as above explanation.

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Next, we have to determine the matrix $S$. Then, its internal elements must be rational numbers or integers owing to sentence. To estimate these factors, the [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) gives good clue. Following descriptions are initial four triples (Of course inverted ordering or sort sequence are also true. However except unit matrix):

$$
\cfrac{1}{5}
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -4 \\
4 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
,\cfrac{1}{13}
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -12 \\
12 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
,\cfrac{1}{17}
\begin{bmatrix}
8 & -15 \\
15 & 8
\end{bmatrix}
,\cdots
$$

To satisfy these conditions, each matrices are applied:

$$
\begin{array}
AA= & \cfrac{1}{5}
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -4 \\
4 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
,&
\cfrac{1}{13}
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -12 \\
12 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
,&\cdots
\\
B= & \cfrac{1}{10}
\begin{bmatrix}
-(4\sqrt{3}+3) & -(3\sqrt{3}-4) \\
-(3\sqrt{3}-4) & -(4\sqrt{3}+3)
\end{bmatrix}
,&
\cfrac{1}{26}
\begin{bmatrix}
-(12\sqrt{3}+5) & -(5\sqrt{3}-12) \\
5\sqrt{3}-12 & -(12\sqrt{3}+5)
\end{bmatrix}
,&\cdots
\\
C= & \cfrac{1}{10}
\begin{bmatrix}
-(4\sqrt{3}-3) & -(3\sqrt{3}+4) \\
-(3\sqrt{3}+4) & -(4\sqrt{3}-3)
\end{bmatrix}
,&
\cfrac{1}{26}
\begin{bmatrix}
12\sqrt{3}-5 & 5\sqrt{3}+12 \\
-(5\sqrt{3}+12) & 12\sqrt{3}-5
\end{bmatrix}
,&\cdots
\\
S= & \cfrac{1}{125}
\begin{bmatrix}
-117 & -44 \\
44 & -117
\end{bmatrix}
,&
\cfrac{1}{2197}
\begin{bmatrix}
-2035 & 828 \\
-828 & -2035
\end{bmatrix}
,&\cdots
\end{array}
$$

As well known, Pythagorean triples exist endlessly so that these commutative matrices (and whole solutions) also exist infinity.

Comment: This is an interesting attempt. Unfortunately, what the OP looks for are matrices with integer or rational entries.